# javascript enum auto-increment?

Tags: javascript, objective-c

In objc I can use the enum like this:

```
typedef enum {
   STATE_A = 1,
   STATE_B,
   STATE_C,
   ......
   STATE_KK = 100,
   STATE_FF,
   ......
   STATE_XXX = 99999
} State;
```

the value of each variable is auto increased (compared to the former one).

but in javascript, I need to:

```
var State = {
   STATE_A: 1,
   STATE_B: 2,
   STATE_C: 3,
   ......
   STATE_KK: 100,
   STATE_FF: 101,
   ......
   STATE_XXX = 99999
}
```

you see I need to specify all the values for each varible and this is really sick when you
got lots of varible there and it gets even sicker when you try to insert a variable in between so that 
you have to ask yourself (what the value it should be ???)

I'm quite new to js and really wants to know if there is a way to use enum in js the way like in other languages
such as objc I mentioned.

Thanks :)

Comment: Why would you need that many states?

Comment: In javascript such a structure does not have sense (at least object-based) because objects do not retain order.

Comment: @dfsq - I think the idea is to register an integer to a key, may be a bit like a constant. I don't know the order after the list is created is important, in other words.

Comment: @JaredFarrish maybe. I just got confused with this phrase *it gets even sicker when you try to insert a variable in between*.

Comment: I can't help but feel that this type of structure should be database driven.  I can't say I really understand what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @dfsq - I see what you mean. I'm not familiar with objective C, but I gather there's some syntactic sugar with that where it "fills in" the gaps. Same outcome, just it doesn't "roll" out the gaps automatically (I think even PHP can do this now).

Comment: What he wants to do is _clear_ he wants to compare enum values so they each need to be unique. Nothing to do with DB structure if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: @dfsq - Like [`range()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) and [`array_fill_keys()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array_fill_keys.php).

Comment: Is 100 a point where you reset the increment seed to 100, or are there 99 values before it?

Comment: I suspect this may be what the OP is referencing: [Object Subscripting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#object-subscripting)

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 6):

its kind of ugly, but you could do:

```
var i=1;
var State = {
   STATE_A: i++,
   STATE_B: i++,
   STATE_C: i++
}
```

Comment: I suspect that kind've misses the overall point (see dfsq's and my comments under the question). It's more of a *pattern fill* I *think*.

Comment: Just need a simple wrapper and it'll be nice looking

Comment: For example, I used ES6 class to wrapper the counter.

Answer (score 2):

How about giving them all an initial value of 0 then setting their values in a loop

```
var State = {
   STATE_A: 0,
   STATE_B: 0,
   STATE_C: 0,
   ......
   STATE_KK: 0,
   STATE_FF: 0,
   ......
   STATE_XXX = 0
}
var count=0;
for(var key in State){
    State[key]=count++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly your goal is to identify states with numbers in order to make them comparable in enums.

**First** [here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tg7uM/) of what I think you meant.

For general enums, here is a nice trick I use:

```
function createEnum(values){
    var res={};
    for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
       res[values[i]]=i;//add the property
    }
    //Object.freeze(res);//optional to make immutable
    return res;
};
```

This allows the following syntax

```
var State = createEnum(["STATE_A","STATE_B","STATE_C"]);
```

This means you don't have to explicitly define an integer value for all the states, one is given. After that you can use it normally

```
State.STATE_A===State.STATE_B;//returns 1
```

If you'd like to fill based on a pattern, you can extend this the following way (assuming your syntax):

```
function createEnumPattern(prefix,range){
    var res={},str="a";
    for(var i=0;i<range;i++){
       var pattern = prefix+"_"+inc_str(str);
       res[pattern]=i;//add the property
    }
    //Object.freeze(res);//optional to make immutable
    return res;
}
```

Where `inc_str` is from [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/23064/21719).
So for example

```
var State = createEnumPattern("State",100);
```

Will return a `State` enum with properties like `State_aa` and so on, if you'd like you can use `toUpperCase` on it to force the upper case convention you use.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your little enum maker that both auto-numbers them and lets you set any values you want (kind of like the features you have in objectiveC:

```
function makeEnum(list) {
    var obj = {}, sequence = 0, current;
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        current = i;
        if (typeof list[i+1] === "number") {
            sequence = list[i+1];
            i++;
        }
        obj[list[current]] = sequence++;
    }
    return(obj);
}

var State = makeEnum(["STATE_A","STATE_B","STATE_C", "STATE_KK", 100, "STATE_LL"]);
```

Anywhere you put a number in the passed in array, it sets the value of the previous enum value and the sequence then continues from that value.